# Segmentation Fault while using wxPython on MacOs Catalina 10.15.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, frontend, wxpython, wxwidgets

For my frontend I'm using wxPython, with python3. I'm having problems with wx.FileDialog: once used the program chrashes if the user clicks outside the program window and clicks back. It gives a segmentation fault 11. Below Relevant code and errors:

```python
def OnInputFindPress(self, event): 
  frame = wx.Frame(None, -1)
  frame.SetSize(0, 0, 200, 50) # Create open file dialog
  openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(frame, "Open", "", "", "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx", wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) 
  openFileDialog.ShowModal() 
  self.inputfilepinput.SetValue(openFileDialog.GetPath())
  openFileDialog.Destroy() 
  event.Skip()
```

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [21165]
```

Comment: could you please post the backtrace and not just the exception? Also - what version of python and wxPython do you use?

Comment: Are you creating a new wx.App() inside an event handler? ??? What kind of snippet of code is that?

Comment: @Igor Python3.7.4 and wxPython 4.1.0. I'm trying to add the backtrace but the post manager freaks out over too much code.

Comment: @Infinity77 I just started learning wx. And now that you point it out id doesn't make much sense to make a new app inside an event handler. Thanks. i removed it but still it does not solve the problem!

Comment: @EliaSavino, you should also remove creation of the new wxFrame. Also for the future reference - you can get the official demo and samples from the wxPython download page and try it out. If it doesn't break - check the code to see what do you do differently.

Comment: You should post your code as a minimal, runnable sample application so we can understand what it is you’re doing. As Igor said, the creation of a new wx.Frame is kind of unusual inside an event handler like that. What is triggering the OnInputFindPress? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: OnIinputFindPress is triggered by a click on a button (wx.EVT_BUTTON). The idea is to have a look for file button like a lot of gui have.

Comment: BTW, Thanks to both of you! it's being definitely helpful and a learning opportunity!

Comment: @EliaSavino, so the script is still crashing even after removing frame creation? Did you try to get the demo and run it? Also, it would be really helpful to get the backtrace of the crash and the full script...